# How to return an object to the user in the java server programming

Tags: java

I have a java servelet segment, which can generate a XML file and print it out on the screen.

The related code are giving as follows

```
public void handle(String target,
                   Request baseRequest,
                   HttpServletRequest request,
                   HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws IOException, ServletException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    baseRequest.setHandled(true);

          // some code to generate process

             PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     // the object of “process” is serialized to generate XML file
     process.serialize(out);
     out.println(process);
     out.close();
```

}

Right now, I  need to return this process object to the user, how should I do that? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "return this process object to the user"? If the servlet is generating HTML, the user is just looking at a web page... Your question isn't clear at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the type of the "process" object you could use a library like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to create a simple XML document.  Of course, if it is of type [Process](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) then your results might be very surprising; in this case there is probably very little information you could serialize and return.